QNAP: Backing up Ubunbu to an internal NAS, Ubuntu on external IP and NAS on internal IP
I have a QNAP NAS which is connected to my internal network on IP 192.168.87.100 and works well for backing up various devices in my home.  I have 2 Ubuntu servers which are on external IP..  One ending in .78 and the other on .79.  They are connected to a netgear managed switch.  My internal router is connected the the same switch but DHCP's an IP from my ISP. That router (which is a DECO wireless) is then connected to a regular 8 port netgear switch and any hard wired devices in my house are connected to it.
I want to be able to backup my Ubuntu boxes to the NAS but since they have static external IP's they cannot see the NAS.  The QNAP has a second network port, I did try setting that up with another external IP and connecting it to the managed switch but when trying to SSH to it from one of the Ubuntu boxes and would not accept the QNAP's admin password.  I can however SSH to the internal IP on the first network port on the NAS..
IS there a way to allow the Ubuntu boxes to use the NAS or should I build a new one just for them? maybe  external drives?

Not a Ubuntu question. Try the QNAP NAS support guys.
